# Export data from excel to word using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I want to export data from a spreadsheet such as name, date of birth, address etc to a letter that I'm writing in word.

I've been following this [tutorial](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/integrate-excel-data-word-document/):

I've had success in populating the information in word using a command button, but i don't want the ugly grey button in word so i tried making a macro and pasted the same script into a macro vba.

here is the script I'm using when trying to make the macro:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim objExcel As Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Case Log.xlsx")

ThisDocument.solicitor.Caption = exWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 3)

exWb.Close

Set exWb = Nothing

End Sub
```

when i run the macro it highlights the word "solicitor" and displays the message "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

I've checked and rechecked and the label name is correct, it works with the command button, i don't understand why it shouldn't work as a macro.

Any helps would be much appreciated.

Comment: The macro has to be placed in a `Module` within the VBA project of the `Document` which contais the `Label`. It should **not** be in the VBA project `Normal` of  `Normal.dotm`. There `ThisDocument` will be the `Normal.dotm`.

Comment: ActiveX controls (what the "tutorial" is demonstrating) are not really ideal for Word documents. Among other things, an ActiveX control becomes a property of the document in which it's located, which is why Axel is telling you about where to put the code. There are alternatives that "fit" the surface of a Word document better. It's hard to make a suggestion without knowing something about what the document should look like, but generally in Word we use Bookmarks or perhaps Content Controls as "targets" for information.

Comment: Please take a moment to read about asking questions on StackOverflow. Two widely divergent requests in a single question violates the site guidelines. Click the "Edit" link below your question and remove the "Secondly..." part. Put it in a new question - you can link to this one for the background information.

Comment: Thanks for the replys, I'm trying to write a letter to clients, so 95% of the info is generic, only the name, DOB, reference number etc needs to differ on each letter, I'm planning on extracting this information from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I found a native solution for doing this.
Mail Merge!
I set one up and saved it, now everytime I open the document, it loads all the info from the spreadsheet which it is already pointing to.

Thanks for all the suggestions